# Does Ansible Support New Application ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Does Ansible support the creation of the new application ELB type.
I dont find anything in the documentation of ansible and in the Github..

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Ansible (version 2.1) EC2 modules use old boto (v2) library under the hood, but ELBv2 support is available only in boto3.